# need script which changes css based on screen size

Tags: javascript, css, onchange, screen-size

I need a js which changes my css based on screen size. Something like this:

```
var i;
i= 15;
j = 1930;
for(screen.width == j px){
    @margin-left:i%;
    i += 0.01;
    j++;
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

rather than js for screen width I'd suggest just using [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)
So for example you would have this in your style sheet:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .var_width {
    margin-left: 10%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .var_width {
    margin-left: 20%;
  }
}
```

(obviously without details I can't give code to do exactly what you may want).

Comment: I tried to do it with media querries but the thing is that my object is freaking out after going over 1930px screen width and if I change the margin in this big steps it won't work.

Comment: Well you can have the max-width checked at any value so the step size is unimportant

Comment: By freaking out over 1930px  what do you mean? (ie could you give us some details)

Comment: If you don't need full cross platform support you could also try out the css [calc function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

Comment: I have customized [this menu](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/HorizontalDropDownMenu/#) and the submenu doesn't stay in the middle after 1930px it just stays at the position after that.

Answer (score 0):

If you target modern browsers, in addition to CSS Media Queries you can use [window.matchMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) to react to media query events in JS and do some extra work if necessary. You can find some more examples at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Testing_media_queries

Comment: would something like this work?: 

if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 1930px)").matches) {
 var i = (15+((window.matchMedia - 1930)/100));
 margin: 0 0 0 i%;
} 
else {
  margin: 0 0 0 15%;
}